# Primefaces GMap OverlaySelect event and poping up an output panel while clicking

Tags: javascript, jsf, jakarta-ee, primefaces, xhtml

I've a probleme in primeface 4. I have a map and I want to see an output panel while clicking on a marked position in the map

```html
<p:gmap  model="#{addMarkers.emptyModel}" id="gmap" streetView="false"  navigationControl="true" mapTypeControl="true"  draggable="true" center="26.959512, -12.821044" zoom="8" type="ROADMAP" style="width:100%;height:500px">
           <p:ajax  event="overlaySelect" listener="#{addMarkers.onMarkerSelect}" id="open1"  update="messages"/>
           <p:gmapInfoWindow  id="infoWindow">
            <p:outputPanel style="text-align: center;  margin: auto">
                <p:commandButton ajax="true" type="button" value="open map"  onclick="PF('dlg').show();" />
```

When i do refresh the page, the problem seems to be solved and surprisingly I get my output panel !
After debuging I found that I have a little problem in my ManagedBeans

```
public void onMarkerSelect(OverlaySelectEvent event)  {
    marker = (Marker) event.getOverlay();
     FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO, "scanning the materials", "Site :"+ marker.getTitle() ));

}
```

Before refreshing I'm getting: event overlay type is unknown and the value is NULL
After refereshing I'm getting event overlay type is "Marker" and the value is #440

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're still struggling with this, I'd suggest to check when the MapModel constructor is used. It should be done in the definition of the bean's field itself or in the postInit funciton, to assure it will be called just once, and not inside a getter or something like that. Example:

```
@ManagedBean(name = EstablecimientoInstalacionesViewDetailBean.ID)
@ViewScoped
public class ViewDetailBean extends AbstractViewDetailBean {

private final static MapModel mapModel = new DefaultMapModel();
[...]
@Override
protected void postInit() {
    refreshMapModel();
}
```

Comment: I was doing JAVA EE web based application to monitor IT equipments (servers, firewalls, switches, routers...) of an X company which have many sites in different cities, I gave them the application & they didn't notice this small bug.
However. I still don't see why it won't work if I put the constructor in a getter,but I just tried that in my local machine and somehow this is working now like a charm !
thank you so much ! planning to report this solution to them in the next days. thanks again.

Comment: It doesn't work with the constructor in the getter because the mapModel is then created and destroyed on each request.